# Digital gauge control in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I am planning to develop the Digital Gauge control in Windows Phone 7. How can i display the Digital numbers basically based on the Timer ?.. Can any one help me in the designing ?

Comment: Can you make it clear what you mean by a "digital gauge" and show an example (mockup?) of what you're trying th achieve? Also be clear by what you mean by "designing"

Comment: Just like.. I want to create the Stop watch application.. So i need a digital display to display that Timer.. Now ?

Answer (score 3):

You can embed a digital font in your project, say under fonts folder, and can use it as follows...

```
FontFamily="/fonts/digitalfontfile.ttf#digitalfontname"
```

where digitalfontfile.ttf is the ttf font file you embedded, and digitalfontname is the font name...